# Typeface not working in Huawei P9 lite

Tags: android, truetype, typeface

this below code works on every android phone but not working in Huawei P9 lite. no errors,please help me.

```
 TextView sint1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);          
 Typeface cFont1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "cf.ttf");
 sint1.setTypeface(cFont1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Android doesn't support the full range of ttf fonts. Here is a [font](http://www.dafont.com/ds-digital.font) that I have used personally in my app. Try using this instead. If this one works, and your urdu one doesn't then your code it correct, and Android does not support your font. If neither work, then something is wrong with your code.

Comment: i tried DS-DIGI.TTF but in the screen it shows default font characters. no digi characters.  DS-DIGI.TTF works on other phones lg leon. sony and samsung j7. only problem is not working on Huawei P9 lite

Comment: In the question it is mentioned that the ttf is working on most of the devices, but it is not working only on honor devices. i have also faced the same issue. Typeface api from these devices is not creating the Typeface from the assets. I think due to the OS customisation by the company, the issue is coming.